# GnuPG / OpenGPG: Recovering public key from private key

Tags: linux, gnupg, public-key, cryptography, private-key

I know that the public SSH key can be recovered from the private using `ssh-keygen -y`.

How can a (deleted) public key be recovered from the private key in GPG (preferably in a way that is OpenGPG compatible)?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

### "Recovering" Public Keys in OpenSSH

`ssh-keygen -y` does not actually *recover* the public key, but just reads it from the private key, where it is always attached if stored in OpenSSH format.

### "Recovering" Public Keys in OpenPGP

Similar for OpenPGP: if exported in an OpenPGP-compliant way, the private key will always contain the public key - import it on a computer you own and trust, and export the public key afterwards. With GnuPG, do something like:

```
gpg --import [private-key-file]
gpg --export [key-id]
```

`gpg --export` will by default only export the public key.

### Where the Public Key Also Might be Found

If you shared the public key, chances are high you either find it on public key servers (eg., http://pgp.mit.edu) or some friend of you has it on his computer (where he can easily `gpg --export` it).